# Find references of Path Variables used in ISM file

Tags: variables, installation, installshield

I have one ISM file created using Installshield. In Path Variables Explorer, I can see some variables defined. How can find if they are used anywhere in the ISM ? I want to remove variables if they are unused.

I am using Installshield 11.5 Adminstudio.

Thanks in Advance.

---Sambhaji

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a program that did something similar only it was looking for unused string table entries.  You can read about it at:

[Use Linq to XML to Clean up  ISString Tables](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2010/08/using-linq-to-xml-to-clean-up-isstring.html)

It would only take a few tweaks to change the query to look at the table that holds ISPathVariables.

Comment: I tried your code. I am getting xmlException while loading the document.

Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.

Does ISM file always have XML format ?

Comment: Ideally it should be in XML format but it could be in Binary ( MSI database ) format.   Open the project up in InstallShield and go to the general screen and change the project format from Binary to XML.   XML is better for source control systems as you get more compact storage and ability to (somewhat) diff versions of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Sambhaji,

ISM files may be binaries or XML, make sure you are using the XML format.

I'm not sure if the option is the same in InstallShield 11.5, but in InstallShield 12, you have to go to General Information-->Project Properties-->Project File Format.

I understand that the Binary format is a bit faster than XML, but in order to keep my projects under  version control I prefer the XML format.

Answer (score 0):

There is one simple way to find references of variable or properties.
Go to Additional Tools -> Direct Editor -> Tables
Just click on Tables and press Ctrl+F (Search option). And type the variable/property you want to search & hit enter.
It will show the reference of variables/properties. Press F3 to see next occurances.