# Is there a way to see if a PATH variable is used in InstallShield?

Tags: installshield, installshield-2018

I am maintaining a old InstallShield installer project with numerous PATH variable defined.

Is there a way from the InstallShield IDE to see if a PATH variable is used at all ?

Or should I just delete one, build, test? i.e. brute force ?

Comment: There is always the direct editor where you can inspect things "under the hood". I don't recall what tables are related to this, but it will be on one of the Installshield-specific tables - prefixed with IS I believe. You could also look inside each component to see what path is specified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find references of Path Variables used in ISM file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606388/find-references-of-path-variables-used-in-ism-file)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking, but what I usually do is to open the .ism file with a text editor and do a search for the PATH variable to see if it is used in any other table.

Do note that if you use Redistributables as installer prerequisites, a PATH variable might be used to point to their location on your machine. This is an InstallShield setting, and will not show in the .ism file, so if you don't know, you might want to check there to be safe. You'll find that in Tools -> Options -> Prerequisites (at least in InstallShield 2013).